# How to replace the content of file containg backslash ( \ ) in its string using PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a config file which has multiple placeholders which i want to replace with some other values using PowerShell but the below code it not able to replace the `%WebClientPath%\www` with value contained in `$WebClientPath` variable. It has this Path in it  "**C:\IWeb\Demo\Main\UIPresentation\WebApp**"
where as `%VirtualApplicationName%` gets replaced by the **IMWeb**

I tried removing **\www** from `%WebClientPath%` and it worked but i want **\www** also to be replaced. I think this is happening because of backslash **( \ )**

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param
(   
    [string]$PathofWebConfigFile="C:\Automate\Web.config"  ,
    [string]$VirtualApplicationName="IMWeb"  
)


# Code to get WebClient Path from PhysicalPath attribute.
$WebClientPath=(get-webapplication IMWeb).PhysicalPath


(Get-Content -Path "$PathofWebConfigFile") | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "%VirtualApplicationName%","$VirtualApplicationName"} | Set-Content -Path "$PathofWebConfigFile"
(Get-Content -Path "$PathofWebConfigFile") | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "%WebClientPath%\www","$WebClientPath"} | Set-Content -Path "$PathofWebConfigFile"
```

Comment: have you tried escaping the "\" character ?

Comment: I did tried something like this but it did'nt work                  (Get-Content -Path "$PathofWebConfigFile") | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "`\www",""} | Set-Content -Path "$PathofWebConfigFile"

Comment: Let me know if using RegEx Escape helps in this context ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slash `\` is escaped by double slashes `\\`, try this:

```
"mypath\www" -replace "\\www","\zzz"
```

This cmdlet will replace `\www` with `\zzz`.

Answer (score 1):

The `-replace` operator is RegEx based, so you have either to

- escape single chars which are Directives for RegEX or
- if a variable content is unknown beforehand better use `[Regex]::Escape()`

You could alternativley use the String.Replace method which is not RegEx based:

```
$_.Replace("%WebClientPath%\www","$WebClientPath")
```